# Not able to fetch info from database when trying from python through exe

Tags: python, sqlite, cx-freeze, python-exec

I've converted my Python application to an .exe using the cx_Freeze Library. Now the GUI appears after I run the exe file, but it cannot fetch data from database, everything else is working.
When this application runs in python environment everything is working fine.

Python version 3.7, database is sqlite3 version 2.6.0.

Please help me in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: When you say it cannot fetch data from the database can you be a little clearer? Do you get an error? Does the application connect to the database correctly?

Comment: Its application GUI so for example if I click button called Name, I should get predefined name in database but nothing is coming whereas if I run the python program I get the results. i hope I clear myself

Comment: Issue identified :- application was creating database but there were no tables in it. when same code was run as python script and it was working because database was created with tables its working... I've copied the same databse into application folder.